# Difficulty in getting social media icons to display inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the social media icons to display in a line rather than stacked on top of one another. I have tried changing the display to inline rather than block but all that happens is that the icons get smaller in size but remain stacked on top of one another.

Here's the code:

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  /*font-size : 16px;*/
}


/*Top Header*/

.header {
  background: #e7e5e4;
}

.header_left {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
}

.header_right {
  width: 35%;
  float: right;
  background: #e7e5e4;
}

.header_right li {
  margin-left: 45%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 4.500em;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.elegantshadow {
  color: #131313;
  background-color: #e7e5e4;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  text-shadow: 1px -1px 0 #767676, -1px 2px 1px #737272, -2px 4px 1px #767474, -3px 6px 1px #787777, -4px 8px 1px #7b7a7a, -5px 10px 1px #7f7d7d, -6px 12px 1px #828181, -7px 14px 1px #868585, -8px 16px 1px #8b8a89, -9px 18px 1px #8f8e8d, -10px 20px 1px #949392, -11px 22px 1px #999897, -12px 24px 1px #9e9c9c, -13px 26px 1px #a3a1a1, -14px 28px 1px #a8a6a6, -15px 30px 1px #adabab, -16px 32px 1px #b2b1b0, -17px 34px 1px #b7b6b5, -18px 36px 1px #bcbbba, -19px 38px 1px #c1bfbf, -20px 40px 1px #c6c4c4, -21px 42px 1px #cbc9c8, -22px 44px 1px #cfcdcd, -23px 46px 1px #d4d2d1, -24px 48px 1px #d8d6d5, -25px 50px 1px #dbdad9, -26px 52px 1px #dfdddc, -27px 54px 1px #e2e0df, -28px 56px 1px #e4e3e2;
}

.header h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
  color: #131313;
  text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'si';
  src: url("../socicon/socicon.eot");
  src: url("../socicon/socicon.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("../socicon/socicon.woff") format('woff'), url("../socicon/socicon.ttf") format('truetype'), url("../socicon/socicon.svg#icomoonregular") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: si;
    src: url(../socicon/socicon.svg) format(svg);
  }
}

.header .soc {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header .soc li {}

.header .soc li a {
  font-family: si!important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-transition: .1s;
  -ms-transition: .1s;
  -moz-transition: .1s;
  -webkit-transition: .1s;
  transition: .1s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 45px;
  -moz-border-radius: 45px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  margin-right: 8%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #e7e5e4;
}

.header .soc-icon-last {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.header .soc-twitter:before {
  content: 'a';
}

.header .soc-facebook:before {
  content: 'b';
}

.header .soc-linkedin:before {
  content: 'j';
}

.soc-email1:before {
  content: '<';
}

.header .soc a:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: #3371b7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Skramshots Photography</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Stewart" />
  <meta name="description" content="This site is about photography by 
    Mark Stewart a.k.a. Skramshots" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, 
    skramshots, photography">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
    scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imageeffects.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/blogsports.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css">


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Niconne" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="soc">

      <div class="header_left">
        <h1 class="elegantshadow">SkramShots Photography

        </h1>
        <br>
        <h2>Move your mouse pointer over the images</h2>
        <br>

      </div>

      <div class="header_right">
        <li>
          <a class="soc-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/skramshots"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="soc-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/webpage.skramshots"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="soc-linkedin " href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mark-stewart-8315443?trk=hp-identity-
    name"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="soc-email1 soc-
    icon-last btn lightbox-61896367686376 email" href="https://form.jotformeu.com/61896367686376"></a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <br>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I don't know how to attach the socicon.eot, svg, ttf or woff which I am using so I hope the code makes sense without them.

What I am actually doing is trying to implement a media query for mobile to have the icons display in a line but I am just trying to get it working as normal first `

Comment: excuse me if I have added excess code but I am trying to supply as much info as I can.

Answer (score 0):

First off remove `margin-left: 45%;` from `.header_right li`. That style is pushing those `li`s to the right, which is forcing them to stack.

You will then just need to add `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;` to `.header_right li` selector to make them display in a line.

Comment: I would also add that you should restructure your html so that the `<ul>` is inside the `<div>` i.e. `<div><ul><li>...</li></ul></div>`

Comment: Good spot, I was focusing on the CSS. That definitely needs to be corrected. @markst33 this is the correct structure of an unordered list:  `<ul><li></li></ul>`. A `<div>` can go inside and `<li></li>` but not directly inside a `<ul></ul>`. In your case, however your opening and closing tags are all over the place :)

Comment: Thats brilliant lads, thanks very much. So in order to add it to the media query it would just be @media screen and (max-width: 400px) { header_right li {
    margin-left: 1%;
         float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
} }

Comment: OK, when I change the main .header_right li to No margin-left and float left it works great. But when I take those same changes and put them into a media query it does not work. I want them to stack at full screen width but for mobile screens I want them to display inline. So I have the following css in my media query   : @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {    
.box {
        width: 100%; }
     
.header_left { width: 100%; }

.header_right {width: 100%;}
        
.header_right li { margin-right: 0; float: left; padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 25px;}}
What am I doing wrong here ?